# PNR Connector unknow, caused by [PNR not found, code: 500325, severity: MODERATE]

Tags: sabre

I am trying to generate PNR. For this purpose I used “EnhancedAirBookRQ” for Air Book “OTA_AirBookRQ”. I used `BargainFinderMaxRQ` for search  then now  I am using `EnhancedAirBookRQ` for Air book and Price Iternary. But I get the error like **PNR Connector unknow, caused by [PNR not found, code: 500325, severity: MODERATE]**

> EnhancedAirBookRQ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
                <eb:From>
                    <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">localhost/sabre</eb:PartyId>
                </eb:From>
                <eb:To>
                    <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">sabre</eb:PartyId>
                </eb:To>
                <eb:CPAId>3W2D</eb:CPAId>
                <eb:ConversationId>testingId</eb:ConversationId>
                <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">EnhancedAirBookRQ</eb:Service>
                <eb:Action>EnhancedAirBookRQ</eb:Action>
                <eb:MessageData>
                    <eb:MessageId>1426190858</eb:MessageId>
                     <eb:Timestamp>2016-02-08T02:37:58-06:00</eb:Timestamp>
                    <eb:TimeToLive>2016-02-08T03:37:58-06:00</eb:TimeToLive>
               </eb:MessageData>              
            </eb:MessageHeader> 
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
                <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3421544930368575840!319427!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            </wsse:Security>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2" version="3.2.0" HaltOnError="true">
    <OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="LL" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="UL" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="UN" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="HL" />
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-03-31T16:05:00" FlightNumber="216" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="S" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="AI" FlightNumber="216" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM" />
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
    </OTA_AirBookRQ>

    <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="true">
        <RedisplayReservation/>
    </PostProcessing>
    <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false">
        <UniqueID ID="JEGYLT" />
    </PreProcessing>
</EnhancedAirBookRQ>


        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

> `EnhancedAirBookRS`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">sabre</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">localhost/sabre</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>3W2D</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>testingId</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">EnhancedAirBookRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>EnhancedAirBookRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>13592644980251760</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2016-03-29T17:54:58</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>1426190858</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3421544930368575840!319427!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
            <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="NotProcessed">
                <Error type="Application" timeStamp="2016-03-29T12:54:58.415-05:00">
                    <SystemSpecificResults>
                        <Message code="ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">PNR Connector unknow, caused by [PNR not found, code: 500325, severity: MODERATE]</Message>
                        <Message code="700201">PNR Connector unknow, caused by [PNR not found, code: 500325, severity: MODERATE]</Message>
                    </SystemSpecificResults>
                </Error>
            </ApplicationResults>
        </EnhancedAirBookRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send this:

```
 <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false">
        <UniqueID ID="JEGYLT" />
 </PreProcessing>
```

Sabre will look for a PNR with that ID, before interpreting the rest of the content on your EnhancedAirBook request. Is that PNR an existing one?

If you are creating a PNR from scratch (meaning you want to book the specified flight/s in a new reservation) you don't need to specify a PNR Id in pre-processing (you can remove the whole PreProcessing element from the request).

Finally, sending  `<PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="true">` will ignore everything the service did after completed, so not sure what you are trying to accomplish there...